# Can't upload image anymore

Tags: support, image-upload

I am not able to upload  an image on Stack Overflow. Open this dialog:

[image: image upload dialog]

but no buttons work.

It's strange but it's working here on Meta.

Comment: Using Norton anti virus? We've seen it cause this issue.

Comment: @Oded, no McAfee. But why I can do it here?

Comment: We load JavaScript and CSS differently here on meta than the other sites (who use a CDN). I am assuming that McAfee is blocking things it shouldn't - the CDN, in this case.

Comment: I can't help but notice the error message "file too large"

Comment: @Epodax - not the issue. Even if it were, the OP didn't even try to upload yet, and even if they did and the image were too big, the layout is completely wrong.

Comment: @Epodax, this notice from beginning, I didn't loaded file at all

Comment: See similar report on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292019/image-uploads-not-working-on-chrome

Comment: Similar here: [Image uploading stuck at Uploading, but none was provided](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357591/55075), but I'm not using any anti-virus, and CDN isn't blocked.

Comment: @kenorb, yes it's the same and looks it's now fixed, please check.

Answer (score 2):

This is not something under our control - your anti-virus (McAfee) is blocking items from our CDN, meaning the image dialog is broken.

You need to allow access to the CDN - or disable your anti-virus (even momentarily) in order to upload images.

Comment: Alternatively, upload them through Meta and grab the link to post on the main site. :)

Comment: Truly rube-goldbergian of you

Comment: better I'll do image upload later from home

Comment: In my case, I'm using Norton.  But I find it odd that this issue just started occurring for me as well.  It hasn't been an issue before until I tried uploading an image today.  Granted, I could still use the normal syntax - because I had a link from a GIF maker - and it worked fine in my answer post.  But using the dialog wasn't possible.

Comment: @OhBeWise - I can only assume that Norton updated their blocking rules recently in a way that caused this issue.

Comment: btw, now upload images is working, nothing was changed from my side, so, I don't think it was antivirus issue.

Comment: @Alexan - we didn't do anything. Could be that your anti virus updated its definitions and is no longer blocking things we are serving.

Comment: and how I can check this? But [this similar issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357591/image-uploading-stuck-at-uploading-but-none-was-provided) not related to antivirus, so I have doubts that mine too.

Comment: We didn't change any image upload code in a long time - so we are pretty sure it isn't something on our end. It is also something that is only happening to a very small number of our users and intermittently at that (and when not intermittent - it is *always* caused by something blocking some of the requests - anti virus, ad blocker or corporate firewall are a few examples).

Comment: @oded please see this answer for possible/probable cause: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357884

Comment: **This answer is wrong** ([in my scenario](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357883/microsoft-advert-appears-to-break-image-upload)). [Seems to be an issue with a Microsoft advert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357884/542251)

Comment: @Liam - oh, wow. I would have never expected that. Thanks for commenting here. I am escalating.

Comment: @Tanner gets all the credit TBH. He noticed the conneciton

Comment: @Liam cheers, hopefully it's simple enough to resolve if it's the ads causing it.

Comment: Verified both the ad issue above and the subsequent solution were true in my case as well.