# Image uploading stuck at Uploading, but none was provided

Tags: bug, image-upload

My steps are:

1. I'm editing the specific [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46635271).
2. Clicking *Image* button from WYSIWYG bar.
3. Modal form is shown and it's already stuck at *Uploading*.

   [image: Stack Exchange Modal form, Uploading, drag & drop]

   Clicking on *Upload*, *Cancel* (both), or X button doesn't have any effect, including uploading, basically none of the links works, only clicking outside of modal takes me back to the page. No messages are reported in *DevTools* (JS console). It happens 90% of time on specific posts, sometimes it just work. Unfortunately I don't have reliable reproducible steps.

Tested in the latest Chrome Canary v63.0.3235.0, also same is happening in my other developer build (63.0.3234.0). The same in *Opera* 47.0, however it works in *Brave* web browser.

To clarify:

- I'm not using any extra *Chrome Extensions*.
- I'm not using any antivirus as per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292019/191655) and [that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357411/55075) post.
- GET request to: https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/img-upload.svg?v=88d0cb836f89 works correctly (Code: 200).
- POST request to: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/validate-body works correctly (Code: 200).
- POST request to: https://stackoverflow.com/render/image-upload?uploadUrl=%2Fupload%2Fimage%3Fhttps%3Dtrue&canDragDrop=true&_=1507545573407 works correctly (Code: 200).
- Basically all requests during the process looks fine and aren't blocked:

  [image: DevTools JS Console]

  In addition I can upload the images in this post (as per above image), so I believe my network provider doesn't block any specific endpoints.

Comment: Is this the same as this? - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357411

Comment: @Pang Yes, same issue. I was searching for similar issues, but couldn't find it.

Comment: However I don't have any antivirus (macOS), I'm not sure about the network, but it works at random (e.g. in other posts), and it also works in other browsers, so the other answer isn't really relevant for me.

Comment: yes, I think it's the same issue as mine, and it looks like uploading images starting working, without any changes from my side.

Comment: We have not changed anything with image uploads for quite a while - we have seen this happen when certain scripts have been blocked or not accessible, be that via anti-virus, ad blocker or corporate firewall (or similar). We get scripts differently here on Meta than on Stack Overflow itself, so our CDN (or the Google CDN) being blocked is still the likeliest reason for this.

Comment: For what's it worth - I can't repro this on current chrome (61) or opera (48), edge (40) or firefox (56). We don't support alpha/beta browsers (i.e. canary builds of chrome).

Comment: just had this problem and after 3 or 4 refreshes it started working properly

Comment: I think [we've re-created the issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357883/microsoft-advert-appears-to-break-image-upload), seems to be an issue with an advert.